# Among the following two stories, which story about the origin of Panchjanya sankh is real.?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavata-purana, harivamsa, truth

According to Shreemad bhagwad the origin of Panchjanya Sankh is the sea, from Samudra Manthan and according to Mahabharat it was gained by Shree Krishna while fighting with demon's in order to save the son of Rishi Sandeepani.

Which one of following story is true?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How did Shri Krishna get the Shankh named Panchajanya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/how-did-shri-krishna-get-the-shankh-named-panchajanya)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.